# How to switch an image from one part to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `col-md-6` bootstrap columns

I want in a column `class="col-md-6 one"` to display the content and in another (`class="col-md-6 two"`) only images.

But currently all content both text and images are in `class="col-md-6 one"`.

The class of all images in the `class="col-md-6 one"` are:

```
class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-520"
```

With jQuery, how is it possible to "crop" the images from the `class="col-md-6 one"` and "paste" it into the `class="col-md-6 two"`?

What jQuery functions can I use for this?

Comment: what? you want to move the <img> tag from one div to another using `jQuery`?

Comment: @LiroyLeshed `Jquery` can manipulate the `DOM`, I think it's possible. Hide the code of one part and display in another

Comment: because I'm going to need a bigger solution using `php` and `wordpress`, I think `Jquery` is simpler. I just need a function or example that I can use with jquery

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following with jQuery:

```
function moveElement(element, targetElement) {
  var $el = $(element)
  var $clonedEl = $el.clone()
  $el.remove()
  $(targetElement).append($clonedEl)
}
```

or in vanilla JavaScript:

```
function moveElement(element, targetElement) {
  var el = document.querySelector(element)
  var clonedEl = el.cloneNode(true)
  el.parent.removeChild(el)
  document.querySelector(targetElement).appendChild(clonedEl)
}
```

or use `jQuery`'s [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) (Thanks to @Roamer-1888)

```
$(function() { $('.size-medium').appendTo('.two'); });
```

Comment: I would probably recommend using `$(element).remove()` rather than `.hide()`. I don't think there's a reason (in this case) to keep the original element in the original position in the DOM

Comment: I thought the same thing and just edited my answer :)

Comment: @LiroyLeshed thanks for the answer, please see the fiddle  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/1288w9bo/)

Comment: I think I've done something wrong, it's not working yet.

Comment: you have a few mistakes. keep the function the way I wrote it and see the updated answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1288w9bo/1/    I made the changes but it still is not working, the link fiddle  of your answer is the same as I sent

Comment: It may be as simple as `$(function() {
  $('.size-medium').appendTo('.two');
});` - http://jsfiddle.net/zvjfzbpr/

Comment: Yes! @Roamer-1888 Thank you very much, you can create your answer to mark as correct.

Comment: updated my answer. simply do this: `moveElement(".one", ".two")` jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fy8m7fr0/1

Comment: Let @LiroyLeshed edit it into his answer and give him the points. He's worked at it harder than I have and I wouldn't have guessed the solution without his efforts.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone. Thank you very much @LiroyLeshed.com

Answer (score 0):

if flexbox is not a problem for you order: X could solve your question without js. if youre interested i can detail it.